# Echo string which has highest number?

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have these;

```
$z1 = substr_count_array($aldi1, "keyword");
$z2 = substr_count_array($aldi2, "keyword");
$z3 = substr_count_array($aldi3, "keyword");
```

substr_count_array counts the number that how many times our keyword is included in that string.
Now I want to echo string that has the highest count number. I want to echo the string which has highest number. How should I do that ?

Comment: use `max` on the 3 variables and then output the associated string

Comment: what do you mean by  highest count number ?

Comment: are the variable names always related ? ie `$z#` - `$aldi#` where # is the same number

Comment: No, variable name doesnt matter. highest count number means how many times the keyword has included.

Comment: It depends exactly what substr_count_array() returns - or are you using the native PHP function substr_count()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store the result from the count in an array. If you store each "aldi" in an array you can do this:

```
$longest = "";
$max = 0;
foreach($aldi as $text)
{
   $count = substr_count_array($text, "keyword");
   if($count > $max)
   {
      $longest = $text;
      $max = $count;
   }
}
echo $longest. " ". $max . " times";
```

Comment: But that doesn't return what OP wants - it echoes the highest **count**, not the **string** with the highest count; and by the way, where does `$k` come from, shouldn't that be `$z`?

Comment: This would still return the count and not the actual string.

Comment: @nyarlathotep and liquorvicar.. you're right.. I thought he wanted the count.. I'll edit my answer..

Answer (score 0):

ManseUK, why not post the answer in an actual answer?

Anyway, he's right:

`echo max($z1, $z2, $z3);`

Comment: He doesn't want to output the highest number he wants to output the string that has the highest number. ie if the highest number was `$z1` then output the string `$aldi1`

Comment: but not what OP originally wanted. He wanted the **string** returning the highest value for substr_count_array, not the highest returned value.

Comment: I dont want to echo the highest number, I want to echo the string which has highest number.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP `max` function : `echo max($z1,$z2,$z3);`